# PowerShell Script Ends in SQLSERVER:\>

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that does a Invoke-Sqlcmd and when the script completes it leaves me in 'SQLSERVER:>'.

Is there a way to tell my script to return me to original directory when it completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method for this is:

```
try {
    $private:oldLocation = (Get-Location)

    # Do Stuff

}
finally {
    Set-Location $private:oldLocation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null
Push-Location "SQLSERVER:\sql\$Server\DEFAULT\databases\$database" | Out-Null        

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query
#More Work

pop-location
```

Alternatively you could push the location of the database you want to run queries/operations onto the location stack. Do work. Then pop the location off the location stack when done.

$Server : Being the server the db is being hosted on
$database : The database name in your database server

The Out-Null isn't required. It just prevents output being pumped into the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is to do this:

```
try {
    Push-Location
    Import-Module SQLPS

    # More code
} finally {
    Pop-Location
}
```

This is especially nice during testing because even when you throw an exception or stop the debugger your original path is still restored.